# A bag has 10 red socks and 10 blue socks mixed up. What is the minimum number of socks to pick to be certain that there are two different colors?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Alice puts 10 red socks and 10 blue socks in a bag. She tells Bob that there are 20 socks in the bag and tells to Bob pick a sock randomly one at a time.  What is the minimum number of socks Bob has to pick to be certain that there are at least two different colors?

Some argue that the answer is 2 but other says 11.

2 because that's the minimum possible (Best case scenario is 1B and 1R)

11 because that's the worst-case scenario (10B and 1R)

Is any of the two answers above correct? How can the question be rephrased to be unambiguous and have a single answer either 2 or 11?

## Update:

For those who argue that the answer is not 2, maybe the word "certain" is confused with the probability of the event happening. The probability of each may differ, but in each of the events below, Bob can be certain that there are at least two different colors in the bag.
So the minimum number of picks is 2 to be certain that there

```
[1R1B => certain, 2 picks, event probability=(10/20 * 10/19)=0.2631]
[2R1B => certain, 3 picks, event probability=(10/20 * 9/19 * 10/18)=0.131]
[3R1B => certain, 4 picks, event probability=(10/20 * 9/19 * 8/18 * 10/17)=0.061919]
...
[10B1R => certain, 11 picks, event probability=5.412544112e-06]
```

Comment: Of course everything is "certain" once you've observed it. The word "certain" in the problem means certain *before* picking/looking at the results.

Answer (score 2):

The key phrase is "to be certain". If he picks 2 socks, he isn't *certain* to get two different colors, because he might get two reds. The minimum number he must pick *to be certain* to get two different colors is 11, because it's impossible to get 11 of all the same color.

Comment: True. but in the best-case scenario, he is already "certain" that there are two different colors by picking only 2, which is also a true statement. You might argue that the best-case scenario is not always "certain" to happen, but the question asks about the minimum number (possible?) of picks for Bob to be "certain" that at least two colors exist, and 2 picks can already satisfy this condition, though the likelihood is not 100%, but possible

Comment: "$2$ picks can already satisfy this condition, though the likelihood is not $100\%$"... how is this synonymous with "certain"?

Comment: The event is not certain to happen, but that's a possibility,

Comment: I added more explanation in my question update